# Recommendation for combinatorics books

Tags: calculus, probability, combinatorics, soft-question, book-recommendation

Previously I studied series, sequences, and convergence from the book *A Text-Book of Convergence* by W. L. Ferrar, and studying through this book was very good for me, because of the advantages that this book contains, and one of the most prominent of these advantages for me is the easy English langauge, and now I want to learn the basics of combinatorial analysis, so I want one book that is good for university students, and it must be simple in its language.

I tried to use the book *A Walk Through Combinatorics - An Introduction to Enumeration and Graph Theory*, it is very good but it is inappropriate for me because it does not have a simple language.

So I want your recommendation.

Comment: I think it is useful to learn English if you want to study mathematics. Most papers and textbooks nowadays are written in English. Is there anything that prevents you from learning the language?

Comment: Combinatorics is often difficult to explain in simple language, more so than other fields of math. I recommend looking for math textbooks that have a version in english, as well as a version in the language you’re most comfortable with, so that you can compare the 2 side by side and hopefully learn the english words and expressions often used in mathematics.

Comment: @iosce do you know some siteweb that give good translation

Comment: I’m not sure sorry. It probably depends on the language you prefer. Someone may have a good recommendation if you edit the question to specify what languages you are fluent in, or create a new question about that.